# Embedded Jetty Server not working for Java Vaadin app

Tags: java, jetty, vaadin, embedded-jetty

I am building a vaadin app with maven that will use an embedded jetty server to run.  I have found a couple examples online and have done my best to integrate what I learned from them into my code, but it is not working.

I have made an `EmbeddedJetty` class:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import com.wndgroup.auction.supportsystem.DashboardServlet;

public class EmbeddedJetty {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/example");
        handler.addServlet(DashboardServlet.class, "/");
        server.start();
    }
}
```

And this is my `DashboardServlet` class:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DashboardServlet extends VaadinServlet {

    @Override
    protected final void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
        super.servletInitialized();
        getService().addSessionInitListener(new DashboardSessionInitListener());
    }
}
```

When I try to run the `EmbeddedJetty` class, I get back this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/ContainerLifeCycle
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.wndgroup.auction.supportsystem.EmbeddedJetty.main(EmbeddedJetty.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 49 more
```

And here is the new stack trace I am getting after importing the `jetty-util jar`:

```
Nov 18, 2015 1:31:58 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
INFO: Logging initialized @225ms
Nov 18, 2015 1:31:58 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: jetty-9.2.2.v20140723
Nov 18, 2015 1:31:58 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStart
INFO: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@35bbe5e8{/example,null,AVAILABLE}
Nov 18, 2015 1:31:58 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart
INFO: Started ServerConnector@880ec60{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Nov 18, 2015 1:31:58 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle setFailed
WARNING: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@3f3afe78: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/Uptime
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/Uptime
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.wndgroup.auction.supportsystem.EmbeddedJetty.main(EmbeddedJetty.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Uptime
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/Uptime
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.wndgroup.auction.supportsystem.EmbeddedJetty.main(EmbeddedJetty.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Uptime
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

I am extremely new to Jetty and Vaadin so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: As always for ClassNotFound... try adding missing libraries (classname + jarfile in google should yield results)

Comment: Have you imported jetty-util jar. Class loader is not able to find ContainerLifeCycle.class file. Kindly check.

Comment: I found that I did not have that imported and have done so.  It seems to have solved my original problem, but I am now running into problems involving jetty.util.Uptime.  Any idea why this is occurring?  (I have uploaded the stack trace to the question) @Priyanshu

Comment: Again Uptime class seems to be missing. Check the contents of JAR file whether it's there.

Comment: It looks like it's not there.  How would I go about adding it? @Priyanshu

Comment: Use this dependency instead.<dependency>
 <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
 <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
 <version>9.3.6.v20151106</version>
</dependency>

Comment: That has the Uptime class in it

Comment: Now I seem to be missing org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/NonBlockingThread.  Is there a different version that has that in it? @Priyanshu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add arbitrary jars to your project, that will never work.

> Use a build tool, (really, can't emphasis this enough!) You have many
>   to choose from.
>
> - Maven
> - Gradle
> - Ant + Ivy
> - Scala/SBT
> - Buildr
> - etc ...

What's going on is that you have multiple versions of jetty present in your classpath.

I see `9.2.2.v20140723` in your startup logs (version is discovered from different places) and references to `org.eclipse.jetty.util.Uptime` which wasn't [introduced until `9.2.6.v20141203`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/07647e8a5f01ad3bc8adc368c5a4d4e1499e293d).

The Uptime class is an in internal class, for [a bug fix related to java8 compact3 and android compatibility](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/07647e8a5f01ad3bc8adc368c5a4d4e1499e293d).

However you also have a `Server` object that is attempting to use this class, which means you have a version of `jetty-server.jar` at a version after `9.2.6.v20141203`, but a `jetty-util.jar` at a version before it.

What you need to do:

1. Use a build tool!
2. Eliminate shot-in-the-dark arbitrary artifact references from your build/runtime.
3. From your `EmbeddedJetty.java` example, you only need a reference to the `jetty-servlet-${version}.jar` (that's it. don't reference anything else, see step #4)
4. let the artifact dependency knowledge do its thing, the build tool will pull in the rest of the artifacts that you need, automatically, and sanely.
5. If you are using the `jetty-all.jar` artifact, quit using it in your project [(that's not what that artifact exists for)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg06030.html).

Comment: So making the versions the same fixed the problem I was having, and the Jetty server is starting now.  but I am running into this error when trying to navigate to the correct url: HTTP ERROR: 500

Problem accessing /example/. Reason:

    javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No SessionManager